# Selenium send_keys doesn't do the same element twice

Tags: python, selenium, sendkeys

I'm trying to send keys to Wordle based on the elements in the HTML, and have found that whenever there is a duplicate of a letter it won't press the key twice.

For example, if word = 'Trent' it will only type 'Tren', but if the word was 'Burnt' the whole word would get sent.

This is my current code;

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.wordleunlimited.com/")


word = "Trent"
letters = []
for letter in word:
    button = "//div[text()='%s']" % letter.lower()
    elem = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, button)
    elem.click()
```

The only workaround I have found for this is to avoid HTML elements altogether and just use the keyboard library. As shown below. Is there anyway to overcome this issue using elements?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from keyboard import press
from keyboard import write

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.wordleunlimited.com/")
write(word.lower(), delay = 0.05)
press('enter')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at what div[text()=''] does after you select 1 t it makes another div tag with that value.

```
"//div[contains(@class,'Game-keyboard-button') and text()='%s']" % letter.lower()
```

you should be targetting the div with a certain class and text.